# JQuery Modal dialog: Overlay is not visible

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am new to JQuery. I am developing a ASP.Net MVC application. In one of the views I am trying to open a JQuery Modal Dialog.
Here is the JavaScript code for this

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        $(".openDialogLink").
        live("click", function (e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("<div></div>").addClass("dialogBoxDiv").appendTo("body").
            dialog(
            {
                modal: true, 
                draggable: true,
                overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000000", opacity: 0.5 }, 
                title: $(this).attr("DialogTitle"),
                show: "puff",
                hide: "puff",
                closeOnEscape: true,
                close: function () 
                {
                    $(this).remove()
                },
            }
            ).load(this.href);
        });
        $(".close").
        live("click", function (e) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });
```

Problem is the overlay for unused area in webpage is not visible. Looks like there is some small setting I am missing.

Help Please.

Comment: Where is your overlay located in your markup? Assuming its a div with a mask. Ive had issues where the overlay wouldnt show, unless it was on the masterpage/layout.

Comment: I didn't add any overlay div in HTML markup. What I thought is the overlay property in JQuery dialog is the one we need to use hence set it to  overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000000", opacity: 0.5 }. Isn't it so?

Comment: Yes. But often with jQuery modals theres a hidden div at the end of the page. Check the guide again and see if you missed any markup.

Comment: @Jaitsu: Yes, missing CSS was indeed the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to work fine with the background overlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/8bwNU/

The jQuery-ui css style sheet uses images for the jQuery stuff you're using. Probably add the css file if you haven't somewhere else already... You can download the components you need from [here](http://jqueryui.com/download).

```
<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The zip file will contain a css file, relevant images and the jQuery-ui javascript file (that you're currently using). The css looks for some images in a folder called 'images', so as long as the images are in your solution in a folder called images and you've referenced your css, it should apply the background overlay.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed expatiation. Yes I missed the CSS reference in my View. Problem is solved. Many Thanks.